# Debugging file handle issues in c#/.NET

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, visual-studio-debugging, filehandle

I have a program that in turn accesses a DLL.  It uses files in various ways, creating them, copying them and establishing them as attachments to an emailMessage object.  I have a 'file in use' error, preventing overwrite of a file.

Is there any tool or technique for easing the process - eg some kind of warning of the creation / removal of handles containing a particular string?  I've looked at process explorer, process monitor (the successor to filemon) etc but no luck.

I can keep hunting, but thought there might be a better approach than continuing my informal investigations through the code.

**EDIT**

Thanks for the comments. Regarding the questions, the structure is a bit complex.  I have my 'client' app which references an 'Engine' dll (in C# also).  Both are my own.  The client creates instances of 'attachments' each of which contain a file reference to various files.  The constructor of that grabs the file referred to, and puts a copy in a temporary folder.  Later, a set of 'actions' builds the email - it adds each attachment as a 'real' attachment to an EmailMessage object.  At various times I dispose of the objects and set their references to null, but if I do it too early then I end up with null reference exceptions.  If I do it too late, the damn things are in use!  I'm sure I can hunt down this specific bug in due course, but it prompted me to wonder if there is a useful standard method used by those in the know.  :)

Comment: My first thought would have been to recommend Process Explorer, but I see you've already tried that. No luck, eh?

Comment: Is the creation of the handles to the file (Filestream etc) completely within your application, or is there external processes involved as well?

Comment: File in use error. do you have access to the code that is Invoking / Creating the file.? if so it's probably not being released properly and or if it's C# code the newing of the file stream improperly could cause this as well.. do you have a sample of the code that creates the files / attachments..  is this DLL managed code or UnManaged code..??

Comment: In reply to the additional info - I think the standard way to hold 'a reference' to a file which can be passed around without worrying about lifetime issues is as a filename.  Make your attachement object hold the filename of the file, not a stream, and then that object won't need to be disposable at all.

Comment: Hi will.  I do indeed do that, but it gets a bit confusing when you start creating an attachment and adding it to the attachment collection of the EmailMessage.  If you add it, then null out the reference, it tends to then ruin it within the emailmessage too.  I must admit I'm not an expert on how reference types work, so I need to investigate some more on where each one is pointing.  Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Procmon will tell you who (i.e. which process) is opening the file, and the (unmanaged) stack of the place that opened it.

The usual cause of this problem in C#/.NET is people opening file streams and not disposing  when they've finished with them.  This means the file stays open until (at least) the next garbage collection, which can be ages away.

Comment: IDisposable and using blocks rock.

Comment: Thanks.  I agree; but have to keep some of the objects for long enough to attach them to the email (see my edit above)

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're looking for a tool to let you know what is locking the file while debugging. If so, you can use [Unlocker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unlocker) to determine the process locking the file.